# How many bytes can be stored in a memory unit that uses 8 address bits and a 16 bit architecture?

Tags: memory

I need help understanding memory. How many bytes can be stored in a memory unit that uses 8 address bits and a 16 bit architecture?

I think it's 2^8 = 256. Is this correct?

Edit: I mean 256

Comment: Assuming that each address refers to 16 bits of memory, as your question seems to imply, I think you are still off by a factor of 2.

Answer (score 2):

It depends.

Firstly "16 bit architecture" is too vague to be a helpful characterization for this problem.  A characterization like that generally refers to the width of registers and data paths (e.g. in the ALU), not how memory is addressed.

Secondly, the answer actually depends on whether the addresses are byte addresses or "word" addresses.  AFAIK "almost all" new processor / instruction set architectures designed since the 1980's have used byte addresses.  But prior to that it was common for addresses to address words of up to 60 bits (or possibly more).

But assuming byte addressing, then an 8 bit address allows you to address 2^8 bytes; i.e. 256 bytes.

On the other hand, if we assume word addressing with a 16 bit word, then 8 bit addresses will address 256 words ... which is 512 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

The base answer is the 2^number of bits. However,long ago sixteen bit systems came up with means for accessing more than 2^16 memory though segments. While an application can only access 2^16 bytes at a time, changing the values in hardware registers allows the application to change which 2^16 bytes of a larger address space are being accessed.

You typically do things like

1. Map buffer 1 to the address space.
2. Queue a read operation to the buffer.
3. Map another buffer 2 to the address space.
4. Read operation completes-map Buffer 1 back so that the data can be accessed.